# Escaping JSON special characters with JSON_QUERY not working

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

A project I'm working on involves storing a string of data in a table column. The table will have other columns relevant to the records. We decided to store the string data column using JSON.

From the table, a view will parse the JSON column into separate columns. The view will also have columns derived from the other main table columns. The data from the view is then used to populate parts of a document through SSRS.

When loading data into the main table, I need to utilize separate tables for deriving the other column values and the JSON column. I decided to use common table expressions for this. At the end of the query, I bring together the derived columns from the different common table expressions, including the JSON column, and insert them into the main table.

I had it almost done until I realized that when I use FOR JSON to create the JSON column, it escapes special characters. I did some research and have been trying to use the JSON_QUERY function to get around this but it's not working. Here is a simplification of the problem:

```
WITH Table1
(
    First_Name_JSON
)
As
(
    SELECT 'Tim/' As First_Name
    FOR JSON PATH
)
SELECT JSON_QUERY(Table1.First_Name_JSON) as first_name
FROM Table1
FOR JSON PATH
```

Here is the output:

```
[{"first_name":[{"First_Name":"Tim\/"}]}]
```

Why is it still escaping? The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/solve-common-issues-with-json-in-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) shows that passing a column that was created by a FOR JSON should make the JSON_QUERY function return it without escaped characters.

I know that this works:

```
SELECT JSON_QUERY('{"Firt_Name": "Tim/"}') as first_name
FOR JSON PATH
```

Output:

```
[{"first_name":{"Firt_Name": "Tim/"}}]
```

However, I need to be able to pass a column that's holding JSON data already because it's pretty long logic with many columns. Using FOR JSON is ideal for making changes versus hard coding the JSON format around each column.

I must be missing something. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite simple:

`{"Firt_Name": "Tim/"}` is valid JSON, so `JSON_QUERY` can return it as is. `Tim/` is not valid so needs escaping first.

[Quote from the docs:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-query-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#using-json_query-with-for-json)

> **Using `JSON_QUERY` with `FOR JSON`**
>
> `JSON_QUERY` **returns a valid JSON fragment.** As a result, FOR JSON doesn't escape special characters in the `JSON_QUERY` return value.
>
> If you're returning results with `FOR JSON`, and you're including data that's **already in JSON format** (in a column or as the result of an expression), wrap the JSON data with `JSON_QUERY` without the path parameter.

---

Given your use case, is it not possible to pass through the JSON to where you need it and un-escape it there? `OPENJSON` and `JSON_VALUE` are capable of this.

Comment: Now I see. I misunderstood the "already in JSON format" part to mean if you pass something to JSON_QUERY that is already in JSON format by way of FOR JSON and not the text needs to be in JSON format when passed through FOR JSON. 
Right, that was what I was thinking next so I'll explore that as well as play around with formatting the columns into JSON format before passing them to FOR JSON. I'd upvote your answer but I don't have enough reputation. Thank you though!